# 30s response delay from IIS

Tags: c#, iis, timeout

I'll admit this is going to be vague but I'll try my best. I have a website that typically sees a few hundred users per day and rarely sees CPU usage above 5%. The website runs on Windows 2012 R2, IIS 8.5, MS SQL Server 2016, .NET 4.5.

The problem is *occasional* requests take 30s before it responds. I put tracing in to see where the slowdown occurs and it's between a controller returning an `ActionResult` and `Application_EndRequest` being called - and it's *always* 30 seconds, +/- 0.1 - and the result is 200 (OK), not a server timeout - OR it's 1-3 seconds at most (ie I've never seen a delay >3 and <30) in hundreds of log entries. The time from `Application_BeginRequest` to the controller returning is negligible, a few tens of milliseconds at most.

What is strange is that only a few users suffer this. I've never seen it happen to me, neither have many others. But a small handful can reproduce it quite regularly, albeit still only maybe 1 in 10 to 1 in 50 times. All have reasonable internet connections (at least *they* say so).

The IIS app pool is set to 4000 queue length and the only mention of 30s is the Ping Period.

Part of the controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public async Task<ActionResult> MyMethod(string x)
    {
        [...more code here, but log the time just before returning...]
        HttpContext.Items.Add("stopTimer", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
        return contentResult;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

The `db` is an `ApplicationDbContext` with nothing fancy, just a bunch of DbSets. The controller method itself does do a "select" query but does not insert/update/delete anything.

Part of global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string stopTimer = HttpContext.Current.Items["stopTimer"] as string;
        LoggerController.LogWarning("c " + stopTimer);
        LoggerController.LogWarning("d " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
    }
```

Log file output:

```
Today at 14:57:10   Warning     c 22:56:40.673
Today at 14:57:10   Warning     d 22:57:10.684
```

I'm at a loss to determine what could be causing this delay. Any ideas what to look for next? Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that IIS is putting the app to sleep and when a new request is comming in the app needs to "boot up"?

Comment: 30 seconds smells of networking timeout. And my guess is, that it happens in the delivery. Do you properly log exceptions? Because usually those timeouts come with Exceptions. Unfortuantely massively Multithreaded operations like Servers, are a ideal ground to accidentally swallow Excetpions.

Comment: @Michael - not in this case, I think, because it's already formed the response in the controller. It just needs to actually send it.

Comment: Ahh, okay so the delay is happening in your code?

Comment: @Christopher, network certainly crossed my mind but I don't know how to diagnose that bit. It is definitely possible exceptions are being swallowed unintentionally, but if some other exception occurs then the user gets a non-specific error. In this case it's returning 200 (OK) with a full payload (actually only a few hundred bytes), albeit after 30s.

Comment: Async controller methods will return almost immediately, the task will still be running and could be swallowing a timeout before a successful retry

Comment: maybe keep an eye on Windows Perfmon metrics to see if your network interface gets spikes in outbound packets? It's a long shot but I suppose NIC queues can cause the OS to put your socket operations on hold

Comment: @Michael, well, probably. But all I can debug is the controller method return point, going into the Dispose method, and then hitting a breakpoint in Application_EndRequest. I don't know what goes on under the hood between those things.

Comment: The controller method wasn't async before this - I made it async in case that was a factor but it didn't make a difference. Perfmon on the network is a good idea - thanks.

Comment: @timur is right, that could happen. If new socket connections are created frequently for each request, that could exhaust the number of used connection on the OS level. For example it is good practice top resue HttpClient instead of creating new once all the time.

Comment: @GeoffM The 30s delay occurs between the controller and Application_EndRequest.  I assume something locked the thread up for a period. I think you may need to reproduce this issue and monitor the CPU/current requests so we would know if this issue is caused by high concurrent requests. The fastest way to find the root cause is capture dump snapshot. By analyzing the managed call stack, we can know what the request is pending on and how to fix it.